# How to prevent a recursive conditional from being infinite in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to model a tree of nodes in TypeScript, where some are "element" nodes and some are "text" nodes (like in the DOM). This can be expressed as:

```
type Text = { text: string }
type Element = { children: Node[] }
type Node = Element | Text
```

And then I'm trying to write a TypeScript utility that can get the types of any potential descendant nodes that occur in the tree. Which I can write as:

```
type Descendants<N extends Node> = N extends { children: Array<infer T> } 
    ? T extends Node 
        ? T | Descendants<T> 
        : never 
    : never
```

Given a set of custom nodes:

```
type Paragraph = { children: Text[] }
type Quote = { children: Paragraph[] }
```

All of these work:

```
Descendants<Quote>     // Text | Paragraph
Descendants<Paragraph> // Text
Descendants<Text>      // never
```

But these both fail:

```
Descendants<Element>
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite. (2589)

Descendants<Node>
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite. (2589)
```

Ideally it should return `Element | Text`.

I understand that TypeScript errors out because it thinks it's recursing infinitely. But is there a way to write this helper such that it works with the generic `Element` (or `Node`) types still?

Here is a [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBRAHuGAbZBvAsAFBFKlIAuAnjMgCoRrlIC8SuFD5AXElOQE4BLYAHMkAXxJkqNVDkjAmrdvAAWgrABN+EYDwByAe00QA2gF0JU0jORGTLORAVMAPknqMi1itWQARaERgTRBFKAAefSROXU0oJHsIAD5HaNiQhJV1LR09JABBfn4QSgjhADMIfg9U8SQfMiQAfg8YxjiEpIbCJr6yVtokd0CoYNDwiNpUxv6kHmAIADdqnrn5pEWV-m9e6T8kAAUQEpESmFVHbI1tXR5PcgsrPZsDgEUAV0NyZGUkNRueR4x1O51UT0kxBevlkBUco3GYXIkU+3xSPlsSAAQvCgnEkZEQSAziALskMQcAMK4sb4yYPcnQzH+GmIyYoeS6ciMojiIA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a type parameter `Visited` to represent the union of already visited types, you can use an extra conditional to avoid traversing those types:

```
type DescendantsPrim<Visited, N extends Node> =
  N extends { children: Array<infer T> } 
  ? T extends Node 
    ? T extends Visited
      ? never 
      : T | DescendantsPrim<Visited | T, T> 
    : never 
  : never
```

For the definition of `Descendents` you can use `never` for the `Visited` parameter as it is the neutral element of `|` (i.e. `T | never = T`):

```
type Descendants<N extends Node> = DescendantsPrim<never, N>
```

This will infer the following types:

```
type A = Descendants<Quote>     // Paragraph | Text
type B = Descendants<Paragraph> // { text: string }
type C = Descendants<Text>      // never
type D = Descendants<Element>   // Element | Text
type E = Descendants<Node>      // Element | Text
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBRAHuGAbZBvAsAFBFKlIAuAnjMgCoRrlIC8SuFD5AXElOQE4BLYAHMkAXxJkqNVDkjAmrdvAAWgrABN+EYDwByAe00QA2gF0JU0jORGTLORAVMAPknqMi1itWQARaERgTRBFKAAFITAAHgA1QShBcghNABokfSROXU0oTOMIAD4WH1IsnJD8lXUtHT0kAEF+fhBKGOEAMwh+DxLxJDKkAH4PbMZc-PtkIdJR2nGUqqQEpJTNWbJR4AgANx7BwjJjsh4F90CoYNDwqMFY1eTUpHdaDNoSzZ4d-d6h772PW8R2kfiQl2uYXIUBiFQmy2mJVYENyUMi0RiPx6GX0RWBx1sSAiIFaIlaMFUjhqGm0ujOnAsVhBNjBAEUAK6GFJUpBqGn1HjE0nk1SMyTEZm+WSNRwokJomIcrnFE4AelVRJJIDJIApLw8nB8hIAQrKgqjwjEhdqRSV1WwOIweHwhKImQSwQBhM1XC3QmKecglNUarH8I1g-w+yGWlDyXRBsj2uPOBP6wMR2QoaN+mGIk5IZPxxTpw0S8RAA)